# MultibyteToWideChar blindly copies invalid ANSI codepoints, WHY?

Tags: winapi, unicode

Please check my code and result:

```
void test_MultibyteToWideChar()
{
    WCHAR wbuf[10] = {};
    int ret = MultiByteToWideChar(1253, MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS,
        "\x98\x99\x9A\x9B\x9C\x9D\xFF", 8,
        wbuf, 10);
}
```

The code aims to convert some [codepage-1253](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1253)(Greek) ANSI bytes to Unicode.

Some input ANSI codepoints(0x98, 0x9a etc) does not have character definition, and I thought  `MultiByteToWideChar` should produce error `ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION`, or, at least, produce `U+FFFD`(REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) in output buffer.

However, `MultiByteToWideChar` silently succeeds, just copy the codepoints(0x98, 0x9a etc) to output WCHAR buffer. I think it is ill behavior.

Any idea on this?

Compile with VS2019 16.11 and run on Win10.1909.

[image: VS2019 debugging result]

[image: Codepage 1253 char table]

**==== Update ====**

In my first image, `MultibyteToWideChar` reported fail by returning 0(=FALSE). I checked again, `GetLastError()` is 1113, `ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION`. But I have to tell you, that error is triggered by the final input byte `\xFF`, not by `\x98`. We can try to convert a single `\x98` and see that `MultibyteToWideChar` returns success. Sure, in my opinion, it is a fake success.

[image: Convert a single \x98 byte]

Comment: It is documented behavior.  Quote: "An invalid character is one of the following:
1: A character that is not the default character in the source string, but translates to the default character when MB_ERR_INVALID_CHARS is not set
2: For DBCS strings, a character that has a lead byte but no valid trail byte"

Comment: Related: [MultiByteToWideChar and invalid characters](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.il.hebrew.vc/c/IIDXGFR6nBM)

Comment: [It,`\x98`, is not an invalid character simply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-multibytetowidechar#remarks) as @HansPassant said but `\xFF` is.

Comment: OK. Even if `\x98` is not "invalid character" according to Microsoft's definition, it is NOT a normal character, right? And it is NOT rational to be converted to U+0098, right? So I think it is a buggy behavior. The key question is, how should I workaround this bug by myself. Is there some API that can tell us `\x98` in codepage 1253 is NOT a normal character?

Comment: Compare `lpMultiByteStr` and `lpWideCharStr`? Or hardcode codepage-1253?